# How to KDE + awesomewm?

Tags: kde, window-manager, awesome

Is there a way to configure awesomewm as windows manager but running KDE as desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mask the KWin systemd service and create a new user unit for awesomewm. See [the entry in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#Use_a_different_window_manager).

Answer (score -1):

The window manager that KDE uses is `kwin`, so you can replace it with any other window manager, including `awesomewm`. One possibility of doing this is setting the `KDEWM` [environment variable](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Environment_Variables#KDEWM) to the binary of your window manager before running `startkde`.

Therefore yes they can coexist together more or less as you want. In my case I have never done it with KDE, but I was using Gnome with `awesomewm` for a while. The truth is that joint use is something uncomfortable and unnecessary. I finally stayed at pure `awesomewm`. But this is just personal opinion.

Comment: This method will not work with current versions of Plasma.